# Best way to handle one ForeignKey field that can be sourced from multiple Database Tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am running into a little bit of unique problem and wanted to see which solution fit best practice or if I was missing anything in my design.

I have a model - it has a field on it that represents a metric. That metric is a foreign key to an object which can come from several database tables.

Idea one:

Multiple ForeignKey fields. I'll have the benefits of the cascade options, direct access to the foreign key model instance from `MyModel`, (although that's an easy property to add), and the related lookups. Pitfalls include needing to check an arbitrary number of fields on the model for a FK. Another is logic to make sure that only one FK field has a value at a given time (easy to check presave) although `.update` poses a problem. Then theres added space in the database from all of the columns, although that is less concerning.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    source_one = models.ForeignKey(
        SourceOne,
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        db_index=True
    )

    source_two = models.ForeignKey(
        SourceTwo,
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        db_index=True
    )

    source_three = models.ForeignKey(
        SourceThree,
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        db_index=True
    )
```

Idea two:

Store a source_id and source on the model. Biggest concern I have with this is needing to maintain logic to set these fields to null if the source is deleted. It otherwise seems like a cleaner solution, but not sure if the overhead to make sure the data is accurate is worth it. I can probably write some logic in a delete hook on the fk models to clean `MyModel` up if necessary.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3

    SOURCES = (
        (ONE, "SourceOne"),
        (TWO, "SourceTwo"),
        (THREE, "SourceThree")
    )

    source_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    source = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=SOURCES)
```

I would love the communities opinion.

Comment: Are you aware of Django's built-in support for [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)? It seems essentially equivalent to your idea 2.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry that looks like a great solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Your second idea seems fragile as the integrity is not ensured by the database as you have pointed out yourself.

Without knowing more about the use case, it's difficult to provide an enlightened  advice however if your "metric" object is refered by many other tables, I wonder if you should consider approaching this the other way round, i.e. defining the relationships from the models consuming this metric.

To exemplify, let's say that your project is a photo gallery and that your model represents a tag. Tags could be associated to photos, photo albums or users (e.g.. the tags they want to follow).

The approach would be as follow:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    pass

class Photo(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)


class Album(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)


class User(AbstractUser):
    followed_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

You may even consider to factor in this relationship in an abstract model as outlined below:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    pass

class TaggedModel(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Photo(TaggedModel):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are looking for a [Generic Relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations):

from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

```
class SourceA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class SourceB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    source = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

There are three parts to setting up a Generic Relation:

> - Give your model a ForeignKey to ContentType. The usual name for this field is “content_type”.
> - Give your model a field that can store primary key values from the models you’ll be relating to. For most models, this means a PositiveIntegerField. The usual name for this field is “object_id”.
> - Give your model a GenericForeignKey, and pass it the names of the two fields described above. If these fields are named “content_type” and “object_id”, you can omit this – those are the default field names GenericForeignKey will look for.

Now you can pass any `Source` instance to the `source` field of `MyModel`, regardless of which model it belongs to:

```
source_a = SourceA.objects.first()
source_b = SourceB.objects.first()

MyModel.objects.create(source=source_a)
MyModel.objects.create(source=source_b)
```